# How to use R data.table for scalable aggregations and counting

Tags: r, count, data.table, aggregate

I am trying to use data.table to aggregate and calculate new values for a table as following:

```
 CARD_KEY Nationality OCCUPATION  PURCHASE_AMOUNT PRODUCT
    1      Poland       Student     $100          Shoes
    1      Poland       Student     $150          Shoes
    1      Poland       Student     $50           Bags
    2      UK           Accountant  $10           Shoes
    2      UK           Accountant  $40           Supermarket
```

The output that I am looking for is something like this:

```
 CARD_KEY Nationality OCCUPATION   Total_Purchases   Purchase_Ratio.Shoes Purchase_Ratio_Super...
    1      Poland       Student     $350                    $250/$350              0          
    2      UK           Accountant   $350                    $10/$350              $40/$350
```

Below is what I did. It works but is there a more optimal way to write this code:

```
result = tmp[,Total_Purchases:=list(sum(as.numeric(Purchase_Amount)))][,
         Purchases_Ratio:=sum(as.numeric(Purchase_Amount)/Total_Purchases),by=c("CARD_KEY")][,
         count(.SD,"PRODUCT"),by=c('CARD_KEY','Nationality','OCCUPATION','Purchases_Ratio')][,
         Purchases_Freq:=freq/sum(freq),by=CARD_KEY]
result_reshaped<-reshape(result,direction="wide",
                 idvar=c('CARD_KEY','Nationality','OCCUPATION','freq'),
                 timevar='PRODUCT')
```

The problem is that the code runs into memory problems. I am running this over hundred thousands of rows of data with around 50 different types of products.

The error is:

> long vector not supported yet: memory.c 1636.

Any idea how I can make this code to scale? or why i am getting the error?

Comment: Why are you using base R `reshape`. It is one of the most inefficient function exist in R. Have you heard of `?dcast.data.table`. Also, where did you take `count` from? Also, what is `freq`? You don't have such column

Comment: And wouldn't you need to remove the "$" signs before any sensible aggregation?

Comment: And also no need to assign to `result` as you assigning by reference using `:=`

Comment: count is from the plyr library. freq is an out put of the count function. i do remove the $. i just left it for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are doing a bunch of things wrongly.

- First - Don't use `reshape` when using `data.table`, you have the much more efficient `dcast.data.table` function for that.
- Second - When assigning by reference (i.e., using `:=`), no need in `list` or creating a copy (i.e., using `<-`).
- R doesn't know what's `$`, so you have to get rid of them first and convert your purchase amounts to integers or numeric values.

Here's a possible solution (thanks to @Arun for some advice):

```
tmp[, PURCHASE_AMOUNT := as.integer(gsub("\\$", "", PURCHASE_AMOUNT))][, 
      Total_Purchases := sum(PURCHASE_AMOUNT)]

dcast.data.table(tmp, 
                 CARD_KEY + Nationality + OCCUPATION + Total_Purchases ~ PRODUCT, 
                 function(x) round(sum(x)/sum(tmp$PURCHASE_AMOUNT), 2),
                 value.var = "PURCHASE_AMOUNT")

#    CARD_KEY Nationality OCCUPATION Total_Purchases Bags Shoes Supermarket
# 1:        1      Poland    Student             350 0.14  0.71        0.00
# 2:        2          UK Accountant             350 0.00  0.03        0.11
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. Really helpful. One problem with dcast is that i don't know how i can use it to have different "value.vars". Notice above that i want to have for each product the purchase ratio, the purchase frequency, etc. What you are showing is great but works only for PURCHASE_AMOUNT. Makes sense?

Comment: Any further brilliant suggestions @David-arenburg? :):) really appreciate the help.